# CSS display multiple span/textboxes inline

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="filter-field">
        <span class="filter-title">Number From</span>
        <span class="filter-control">
            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="FilterNumberFrom" runat="server" />
        </span>
        <span class="filter-extension">To</span>
        <span class="filter-control">
            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="FilterNumberTo" runat="server" />
        </span>
    </div>
```

and this stylesheet:

```
    .filter-field {
        height: 20px;
        display: inline;
    }

    .filter-title {
        width:90px;
        display: inline;
        padding-right:10px;
    }

    .filter-extension {
        width: 40px;
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .filter-control {
        display: inline;
    }
```

but each span is displayed on a new line like this:

> Number From
>
> TextBox
>
> To
>
> TextBox

when it's supposed to be something like

> Number From **[space]** TextBox **[more
>   spaces]** To **[space]** TextBox

How can I achieve this through css without changing the tags I'm using? (actually read: without using tables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have displays inline already, you have some *other* CSS (that has a more specific selector) creating the `block` type display.  Or...the textboxes (whatever the rendered version looks like) are `display: block;` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Those custom ASP textboxes are almost certainly rendering the textbox within a `<div>`.  Adding this to your CSS should do the trick:

```
.filter-control * { display:inline !important;}
```

If that textbox control accepts the CssClass attribute, you could also try

```
.inline { display:inline; }

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="FilterNumberXXXXXX" runat="server" CssClass="inline" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a block-level element such as a paragraph or heading:

```
<div class="filter-field">
    <p>
      <span class="filter-title">Number From</span>
      <span class="filter-control">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="FilterNumberFrom" runat="server" />
      </span>
      <span class="filter-extension">To</span>
      <span class="filter-control">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="FilterNumberTo" runat="server" />
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Your styles shouldn't need to be set to inline if they're spans, so your CSS becomes:

```
.filter-field {
    height: 20px;
}

.filter-title {
    width:90px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.filter-extension {
    width: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.filter-control {

}
```

At worst, you might replace your `display: inline;` declarations with `float: left;` but I don't see why you'd need to.

If you are still having problems, I would suggest your span styles are probably inheriting a `display: block;` property from elsewhere in your CSS.

Comment: Ok, you're definitely inheriting styles from elsewhere in the page.  You should use Firebug to trace through your styles and see which ones are affecting your page elements.  A well-constructed style sheet should allow you to put any element on any part of the page without it inheriting unwanted / unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to check which rules are being applied to your elements. As Nick suggested there is probably a more specific selector adding a display: block style to the spans that should be inline by default.

If there is a specific rule (based on an id) you can make your rules more specific by:

- Adding an id to your div and making your css rules apply to that id
- Finding the applied rule, to which ID it refers, and making your CSS rules apply to that ID:

  `#the_id .filter-field span {
      display: inline;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.filter-field {
    height: 20px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you actually don't mean to display a box (div) but a paragraph (p).   You can do the following and it should work.

In your styles:

```
 .filter-field span{
     padding-right:10px;
 }
```

In your markup:

```
<p class="filter-field">
    <span class="filter-title">Number From</span>
    <span class="filter-control">
        Hello
    </span>
    <span class="filter-extension">To</span>
    <span class="filter-control">
        Goodbye
    </span>
</p>
```

Also remember that CSS inherits rules, so the problem could be somewhere else. Using Firebug or any other browser inspection tool could de helpful to determine what's going on.